# Prove the function is decreasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to prove that $z=log\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-96.3}$ is monotonically decreasing.

Attempt:Assume $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$,then $\gamma_1-96.3<\gamma_2-96.3$

then $\frac{1}{\gamma_1-96.3}>\frac{1}{\gamma_2-96.3}$

I am stuck here, because we cannot multiply the left side by $\gamma _{1}$ight side by $\gamma_{2}$ t will ruin the inequality, should I take another approach?

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-96.3}=1+\frac{96.3}{\gamma-96.3}$$
and then use your inequalities.

Comment: My bad did the wrong problem in the book but thanks for the answer